# Merge JSON files excluding duplicates in JSON strings

Tags: javascript, java, json

I have two JSON strings `students1` and `students2`. I would like to merge these 2 strings by excluding duplicates. I have the following working solution in JavaScript. How do I make it work in Java?

```js
    const students1=[{studentId: "0001", name: "Joe", class: "1"},{studentId: "0002", name: "john", class: "1"},{studentId: "0003", name: "Max", class: "1"}],
          students2=[{studentId: "0001", name: "Joe", class: "1"},{studentId: "0002", name: "john", class: "1"},{studentId: "0003", name: "Max", class: "1"},{studentId: "0004", name: "Jony", class: "1"}],
          allstudents = Object.values(students1.concat(students2).reduce((r,o) => {
            r[o.studentId] = o;
            return r;
          },{}));
    console.log(allstudents);
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Map` data structure. Basically like you wrote it overrides the student object if the student object has the same `studentId`.

```
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        List<Student> oldStudents = Arrays.asList(new Student("001", "Joe", "1"));
        List<Student> newStudents = Arrays.asList(new Student("001", "john", "2"));
        Map<String, Student> studentMap = new HashMap<>();
        
        for(Student s : oldStudents) {
            studentMap.put(s.studentId, s);
        }
        
        for(Student s : newStudents) {
            studentMap.put(s.studentId, s);
        }
        // If you want to see the output as list
        System.out.println(studentMap.values());
     }
}

class Student {
    String studentId;
    String name;
    String studentClass;
    
    Student(String studentId, String name, String clas) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
        this.name = name;
        this.studentClass = clas;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{studentId: " + studentId + ", name: " + name + ", studentClass: "+ studentClass + "}";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using [Jackson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind):**

Let's first create a `Student` class:

```
public class Student {
    @JsonProperty(value = "studentId")
    private int id;
    @JsonProperty(value = "name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty(value = "class")
    private String clazz;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", clazz='" + clazz + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) { // by id
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Student student = (Student) o;
        return id == student.id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() { // by id
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }
}
```

Then we deserialize the `JSON`s and add them all to a `Set`:

```
String studentsJsonStr1 = "[{ \"studentId\": \"0001\", \"name\": \"Joe\", \"class\": \"1\" }, { \"studentId\": \"0002\", \"name\": \"john\", \"class\": \"1\" }, { \"studentId\": \"0003\", \"name\": \"Max\", \"class\": \"1\" }]";
String studentsJsonStr2 = "[{\"studentId\": \"0001\", \"name\": \"Joe\", \"class\": \"1\"},{\"studentId\": \"0002\", \"name\": \"john\", \"class\": \"1\"},{\"studentId\": \"0003\", \"name\": \"Max\", \"class\": \"1\"},{\"studentId\": \"0004\", \"name\": \"Jony\", \"class\": \"1\"}]";

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

List<Student> students1 = objectMapper.readValue(studentsJsonStr1, new TypeReference<List<Student>>() {});
List<Student> students2 = objectMapper.readValue(studentsJsonStr2, new TypeReference<List<Student>>() {});

Set<Student> studentSet = Stream.of(students1, students2)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());

studentSet.forEach(student -> System.out.println(student));
```

Output:

```
Student{id=1, name='Joe', clazz='1'}
Student{id=2, name='john', clazz='1'}
Student{id=3, name='Max', clazz='1'}
Student{id=4, name='Jony', clazz='1'}
```